# How to set focus inside custom control in CKEditor5

Tags: ckeditor5

I want to add input into text editor content area and be able to write text into it. I was able to insert input, but when I click it, the focus goes back into the text editor content area. Here is a code:

```
 function createCustomInputPlaceholder(writer) {
            const container = writer.createContainerElement('span', {
                class: 'custom-dropdown-placeholder',
                style: 'display: inline-block; position: relative;'
            });

            const getEditableField = new Promise((resolve) => {
                const content = writer.createUIElement('span', {}, function (domDocument) {
                    const editableField = document.createElement('input');
                    editableField.type = 'text';
                    editableField.style.display = 'inline-block';


                    editableField.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
                        event.stopPropagation();
                    });

                    editableField.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            editableField.focus();
                    });

                    resolve(editableField);

                    return editableField;
                });

                writer.insert(writer.createPositionAt(container, 0), content);
            });

            getEditableField.then((editableField) => {
                editor.ui.focusTracker.add(editableField);
            });

            return toWidget(container, writer);
        }
```

Will appreciate any help.

I have found that I need to use focusTracker, but it also didn't help.

Comment: `focusTracker` is used many times in the original javaScript source. I'd suggest to have a look at it and try to implement it in your own code.